# What questions to ask a prospective employer when receiving a job offer?

Tags: employment, job-offer

What questions to ask a prospective employer when receiving a job offer?

Answer (score 5):

There are many, given that this is a financial site, relevant questions would include (presuming they are not spelled out):

- Pay, overtime policy and regular working hours
- For some jobs - what are the on-call requirements, how is that compensated
- The generalities of the benefit plan (is there one)
- How does vacation accrue; does it go up with number of years?

Pay, overtime and on-call should all be in any comprehensive job offer.  Vacation may be also.
Good Luck

Comment: +1. On the benefit plan, specifically I would ask about: pension, medical / dental insurance, and life insurance. Also death in service - can your benefits pass to your spouse etc?

Answer (score 2):

Ask for a copy of all documents you will be required to sign as a condition of employment.  Intellectual property and non-compete agreements (depending upon jurisdiction) may have a significant impact on your future employability that overshadow the current offer.

Answer (score 1):

- If there is a retirement / pension or other type of investment plan.
- What kind of plan is it?  How is money added to the plan?
- When are you eligible for the plan?
- What types of matching, if any, are available?
- When are you fully vested in the plan?
- If there are stock options, what are the requirements for that plan?
- What sort of perks like association discounts are there?  Can you save money on your gym membership?
- Is there a credit union?
- What is the pay schedule? (so you can make sure you can still meet your bills on time)
- When do you get your first paycheck?  I have a job where you get paid about a week after the pay period, so the first month on the job I didn't get a check.